# Elasticsearch TTL enabled on existing index

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot find good documentation on the Elasticsearch TTL field. I have an index that has documents already stored in it. If I then enable the TTL on the index, does that new TTL apply to the existing documents?

Similarly, if I modify the default TTL later, does that new TTL apply to existing documents or only to new documents from that point forward?

Comment: We just implemented Elasticsearch as well.  I don't know that the answer to your question is in here, but it has helped me some already. http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this the first time, but the elasticsearch documentation does explain this behavior.

Source: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html

> You can dynamically update the default value using the put mapping API. It won’t change the _ttl of already indexed documents but will be used for future documents.